# When redirecting with 301 landing page gives error

Tags: apache2

I am redirecting a domain to another website that I don't have access to.  For example, when somebody enters www.mydomain.com in the url, I want them redirected to www.example.com/test.aspx?q=10.

If I just type "http://www.example.com/test.aspx?q=10" in the address bar, I get taken there as expected.  When I redirect to that exact address, I get an error.  The website loads, but it is an error page created by the website.

My question is, is this likely something on the website that I don't have control of, such as some code like "if http.request == 301 {give error}".

Note, this also happens on a 303 request.

Here is how I am redirecting:

```
<VirtualHost 1.1.1.1:80>
    ServerName www.mydomain.com
    Redirect 301 / http://www.example.com/test.aspx?q=10
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your assumption of the third-party website blocking it is correct. It could be something like it's checking the referring page using HTTP_REFERER?

Maybe you could try removing the HTTP_REFERER

Can you elaborate what you mean when you say you get an error?

Comment: If I am redirecting to example.com/test.aspx?q=10, I get sent to example.com/error.aspx?error=somecode.  To add, if I type in "mydomain.com", it redirects correctly.  If I type in "www.mydomain.com", I get the error page.

Comment: the www.mydomain.com not working, while mydomain.com working seemed to be a caching issue.  My problem seems to be solved.